# instascan - QR code scanner JavaScript library issue

Tags: javascript

I have to implement a JavaScript based QR scan code feature. I am using the `instascan.min.js` as my JavaScript library, however my code is giving me the below error while the browser is starting to scan QR code, but the camera doesn't start.

I have searched for solutions, but haven't found anything. How can I fix this problem or is there another library that is better suited for this?

Here is the error I get:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found

Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
    <head>  
      <title>Document</title>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="./instascan.min .js"></script>
     </head>

     <body>
       <video id="qrcam"></video>
       <input type="text" id="address">
     </body>

     <script>

      var qr = new Instascan.Scanner({
       video:document.getElementById("qrcam")
     });
      qr.addListener('scan',function(data){
      document.getElementById("address").value = data;
       console.log(data);
       });
        Instascan.Camera.getCameras().then(function(cameras){
    if (cameras.length > 0) {
          qr.start(cameras[0]);
        } else {
          console.error('No cameras found.');
        }
       }).catch(function(err){
       console.log(err);
      })

    </script>
     </html>
```

Comment: Are you running this from the file system? or from a web server (even local?) Might be a permissions issue.

Comment: may be user esue or package ,like to install node js                             for more follow the link   https://github.com/schmich/instascan/issues/177 another link   https://github.com/schmich/instascan/issues/152

Comment: Voting to close, as this looks like a typo: `instascan.min .js` should be `instascan.min.js`.

Answer (score 0):

Please Pay attention at the space. <when you include your script

t type="text/javascript" src="./instascan.min .js"

Maybe it